# How to define directives on vue3 compositionAPI?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, vue-composition-api, vue-sfc

How to define and use directives on vue3 composition api with the new syntactic sugar in SFC `<script setup>` format?
With **options API** it used to be like this

```
import click_outside from "@/directives/click-outside.js";
export default {
  directives: {
    "click-outside": click_outside,
  }, 
  ...
}
```

click-outside.js

```
<script setup>
import {defineProps, onBeforeMount, onUnmounted, directive } from "vue";

const onBeforeMount = (el, binding) => {
  ...
};
const onUnmounted = (el) => {
 ...
};
</script>
```

I couldn't figure out the same counterpart code in **composition API**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Feature parity with regular `script` SFC is achieved in 3 different ways.

`props` argument from `setup` and `props`, `emits`, `expose` fields from component options are provided by using [`define...` helpers](https://v3.vuejs.org/api/sfc-script-setup.html#defineprops-and-defineemits).

`context` (only `slots` and `attrs` properties) argument from `setup` is provided by using [`use...` helpers](https://v3.vuejs.org/api/sfc-script-setup.html#useslots-and-useattrs).

`components` and `directives` are indirectly provided by using [imports of the same name](https://github.com/vuejs/rfcs/blob/master/active-rfcs/0040-script-setup.md#using-components).

The rest of features (e.g. `name` property) are still provided by [`script` element](https://v3.vuejs.org/api/sfc-script-setup.html#usage-alongside-normal-script) that can coexist with `script setup`.

Comment: With Vue >= 3.3, you can now use https://blog.vuejs.org/posts/vue-3-3#defineoptions to set a name without a separate script block 

Answer (score 3):

@Estus Flask's answer is enough but just to clarify, you just import directives like you do with components with **PascalCase** or **camelCase** and you can directly use it in your templates.

```
<script setup>
import vClickOutside from "@/directives/click-outside.js";
const outside = () =>{ ... }
...
</script>
<template>
...
<div v-click-outside="outside">
...
...
</template>
```

Comment: But how does one actually **define** a directive? What does `click-outside` look like?

Comment: @theberzi well, I assume it's something like that https://vuejs.org/guide/reusability/custom-directives.html#directive-hooks

Answer (score 0):

**Import directives:**

```js
import click_outside from "@/directives/click-outside.js";
const vClickOutside = click_outside;
```

**And Use:**

```html
<div c-click-outside>...</div>
```